# Datagrid itemrenderer performance issue

Tags: flex4

I have a datagrid with a custom itemrenderer for coloring cells, rows and columns.When i change the color of row sometimes it is perfectly shown but sometimes one or more cells are not colored. I didn't find the reason behind. Can anybody please give any hints on that?

Here is my custom itemrenderer code below..

```
   override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,   unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {   
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

             bd.setStyle("backgroundColor",getStyle("bgColor"));//bordercontainer   
            lbl.setStyle("fontSize",getStyle("fontSize"));//label in //that bordercontainer
            lbl.setStyle("fontFamily",getStyle("fontFamily"));
            lbl.setStyle('color', getStyle("fgColor"));
        }
```

and I'm using AdvancedDatagrid and using styleFunction in it..

```
public function applyFormat(data:Object,col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object {
   var obj:Object = new Object();
   for each(var taskFontFormatVo:TaskFontFormatVo in data.taskFontFormats){
      if(!taskFontFormatVo.barchartView ){
      if(col.headerText == taskFontFormatVo.columnName){
      var bgColor:String = "0x"+taskFontFormatVo.bgColor;
var fgColor:String = "0x"+taskFontFormatVo.fgColor;
var fontSize:Number = taskFontFormatVo.fontSize;
var fontFamily:String = taskFontFormatVo.fontFamily;
obj.bgColor = bgColor;
obj.fgColor = fgColor;
obj.fontSize = fontSize;
obj.fontFamily = fontFamily; 
break;
}
}
}
return obj;
}
```

Comment: you dont seem to set colours all the time - eg if col.headerText != taskFontFormatVo.columnName then nothing happens - so styles will remain on settings from previous call to applyFormat

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've used this condition to check whether color is exists for that column or not.Color is perfectly retrieved (checked in debug) but sometimes it is shown perfectly but sometimes not.